# Book about teenagers who develop powers, including a girl who could shapeshift

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I’m trying to remember the name of a book I read about a decade or so ago.

I think the main character was a boy who was developing some sort of superpower and might’ve been trying to hide it? I vividly remember him meeting a girl who could shapeshift and her talking about staring into the mirror as her face melted and moved around when she discovered her powers. I think they get taken to some lab to get experimented on as well? Evil woman scientist, I think??

The cover was bright and colorful- pretty sure there was a cut-out area on it that drew me in. This was definitely for a young adult/teenaged audience.

Comment: Sounds like the book Midnight's Children by Salman Rushdie. Very colorful cover, a girl who could shapeshift, evil woman scientist. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/MidnightsChildren

Comment: Just glanced at it- I don’t think that’s it, but thank you for trying!

Comment: see if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VoluntaryShapeshifting/Literature